# Make query more configurable and readble

Tags: spring-boot

I'm a newbie to JAVA Spring boot world (Have web experience before: ROR)

I'd like to know is it possible to use built-in lib to make the query chainable and configurable? Thanks

## Current code

public interface TransactionJpaRepo extends JpaRepository {

> > @Query(value = "select  transaction_id, lat, lng,  from transactions WHERE (lat BETWEEN 25.02523972362298 AND 25.043942712896815 ) AND (lng BETWEEN 121.52079460571292 AND 121.53802511642459) , nativeQuery = true)

```
List<RealEstateTransaction> findTargets();
```

}

## Expected code

public interface TransactionJpaRepo extends JpaRepository {

```
// @Query(value = "select  transaction_id, lat, lng,  from transactions WHERE (lat BETWEEN 25.02523972362298 AND 25.043942712896815 ) AND (lng BETWEEN 121.52079460571292 AND 121.53802511642459) , nativeQuery = true)
List<RealEstateTransaction> findTargets(Decimal lat, Decimal lng, ....){
    QueryBuilder().
    addFilter({lat: lat}).
    addFilter({lat: lng}).
    ....;

};
```

}

Comment: you may have a look at criteria queries f.e: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

Comment: Awesome, I need this kind of direction! thanks so much~